# GDAL cutline Syntax Error, clip Polygon from rasterfile with respect to shapefile

Tags: python, gdal, shapefile, geopandas, rasterio

I have Eastcoast.shp file and my raster input file="myrasterfinal77.tif"
output file= "myrasterfinal77_out.tif"

So with respect to Eastcoast.shp shapefile i want to extract same polygon image from my myrasterfinal77.tif input file and generate a output file "myrasterfinal77_out.tif"

```
Error Message i am getting 
    gdalwarp -cutline "Eastcoast.shp" -crop_to_cutline -dstnodata "-9999.0" "myrasterfinal77.tif" "myrasterfinal77_out.tif"
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

For that i am using gdalwarp but i am getting syntax Error.

```
gdalwarp -cutline "Eastcoast.shp" -crop_to_cutline -dstnodata "-9999.0" "myrasterfinal77.tif" "myrasterfinal77_out.tif"
```

Below is my myrasterfinal77.tif image
[image]

Below is my shapefile plot image.
[image]

So i want same latitude longitude polygon raster tiff image to generate outside polygon nodata.
I want only the polygon area.

Error Message i am getting is below :-
[image]

Comment: Any suggestion for above question?

Comment: If you can show an error message when executing the command, it will help to get an answer.

Comment: @binzo     gdalwarp -cutline "Eastcoast.shp" -crop_to_cutline -dstnodata "-9999.0" "myrasterfinal77.tif" "myrasterfinal77_out.tif"
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: The error message "SyntaxError: ..." is from Python, not from gdalwarp.
You may find the following link to be helpful on how to invoke the gdal command from Python. [https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/178048/gdal-translate-error](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/178048/gdal-translate-error)

Comment: @binzo,
Thanks for suggestion
As per the provided link i modified my code, now i am getting 1 as an output ,
import os
os.system("gdalwarp -cutline 'Eastcoast.shp' -crop_to_cutline -dstnodata '-9999.0' " + "myrasterfinal77.tif" + " " +  "myrasterfinal77_out.tif")

Comment: The output of 1 is the return value of the python function os.system, indicating that the gdalwarp command is failing for some reason. If you can run the gdalwarp command on the command line, I suggest you run it and check the error messages from gdalwarp.